# How to make data retrieved from an API in flask shown in a new html?

Tags: python, html, json, api, flask

I have processed the data retrieved from some API in a flask route, extracted the json needed and then stored it in a dictionary. Now, how do I make the processed data appear in a new HTML? Is it a good way to preprocess the data in a flask function, what if the preprocess takes a lot of steps?

Flask python code  `x.py`:

```
@app.route('/test', methods = ['GET'])
def get_from_api():
    url = "https://xxxx"
    API_KEY = "xxxx"
    params = {
    'token' : API_KEY
    }
    response = requests.get(url, params).json()
  
    city = response['city']
    state = response['region']
    postal = response['postal']
    conutry = response['country']
    location = response['loc']
    data = {
        "city" : city,
        "state" : state,
        "postal" : postal,
        "country" : conutry,
        "location" : location
    }
```

Next is the `x.html` for displaying the data

```
<div class = "element_val">
                <li><div id = "city">null</div></li>
                <li><div id = "state">null</div></li>
                ... 
                <li><div id = "location">null</div></li>
</div>
```

How to retrieve the data in flask and put the data in html, and make the html be rendered in `'/test'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_route():
    user_details = {
        'name': 'John',
        'email': 'john@doe.com'
    }

    return render_template('test.html', user=user_details)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- use {{}} to access the render_template vars-->
        <p>{{user.name}}</p>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```